# JQuery Remove name/value pair from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which I populate as following. How do I remove an element from the array?

```
myArray.push( { "name": "one", "value": "1" } );
myArray.push( { "name": "two", "value": "2" } );
```

Update: I would have to remove specific element from the array, say { "name": "one", "value": "1" } element from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) to filter out the one you want to remove

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push( { "name": "one", "value": "1" } );
myArray.push( { "name": "two", "value": "2" } );
myArray = jQuery.grep(myArray, function(value) {
  return value.name != "one"; // return only if name isn't "one"
});
console.log(myArray); // now myArray doesn't contain  { "name": "one", "value": "1" }  in the array
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UR4uc/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use built-in functions (links : [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)) :

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
a.splice(1, 1); // [2]     a -> [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.splice(1, 2); // [3, 4]  a -> [1, 5, 6]
a.pop();        // 6       a -> [1, 5]
a.shift();      // 1       a -> [5]
```

Or create your own functions to check some criteria :

```
// returns the removed element

function removeFirst(array, fn) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (fn(array[i]) !== true) i++;
        else return array.splice(i, 1)[0];
    }
}

// returns an array containing the removed elements

function removeAll(array, fn) {
    var i = 0, removed = [];
    while (i < array.length) {
        if (fn(array[i]) !== true) i++;
        else removed.push(array.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Usage examples :

```
var array = [
    { name: 'one', value: 11 },
    { name: 'one', value: 1 },
    { name: 'two', value: 2 },
    { name: 'three', value: 3 },
    { name: 'four', value: 4 }
];

// removed -> { name: 'one', value: 1 }

var removed = removeFirst(array, function (item) {
    return item.name === 'one' && item.value === 1;
});

// removed -> [{ name: 'two', value: 2 }, { name: 'three', value: 3 }]

var removed = removeAll(array, function (item) {
    return item.name.charAt(0) === 't';
});

// array -> [{ name: 'one', value: 11 }, { name: 'four', value: 4 }]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push( { "name": "one", "value": "1" } );
myArray.push( { "name": "two", "value": "2" } );


//console.log(myArray.toSource()); //FF displays output, google chrome gives error

alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
//output   [{name:"one", value:"1"}, {name:"two", value:"2"}]



var index = myArray[ 'one' ];
myArray.splice(index, 1);

//console.log(myArray.toSource());   //FF displays output, google chrome gives error

alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
//output  [{name:"two", value:"2"}]
```

Comment: @wared I tested and posted. To cross-verify, just now tested again and I get the result as I posted : [{name:"one", value:"1"}, {name:"two", value:"2"}]  then  [{name:"two", value:"2"}]   I see the output on my firebug console.

Comment: @wared  Yes, you are correct. Google Chrome shows error as you mentioned. I tested in Firefox (firebug). I've added the code to display the output. Problem was only in displaying the output. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry! Now I understand, this is not a standard feature : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSource. Sorry again :/

Comment: You will hate me... `console.log(index)` prints `undefined`. I guess `undefined` is treated as `0` by `splice`. So, your suggestion will always remove the first element.

Comment: Making a single check of the overall code is not enough if you're not able to predict the result of each constituent parts.